# Flashes on monitors with Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, lenovo, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad X1 Carbon with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. I've enabled the intel-microcode firmware.
I'm using two external monitors with a ThinkPad OneLink+, and I often get flashes on the monitors. They happen especially when using for example Chrome Developer Tools in emulation mode. They happen (I think) when the system has to perform frequent complicated repaints of the screen. 
They also happen when I'm working without the external screens, but less frequently.
They are very annoying for the eyes.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be fixable (only ?) through a BIOS update: ["(Fix) Fixed an issue where WQHD LCD panel might have flicker."](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/uu/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-X-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-X1-CARBON-TYPE-20HR-20HQ/downloads/DS120391).

Comment: See also https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/X1-Carbon-5th-BIOS-1-22-removes-Panel-Self-Refresh-Option/td-p/3734898

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check (and experiment) with system firmware.  See my question (and proposed answer) here: [External display on USB-C blinks on Lenovo X1 Carbon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200370/external-display-on-usb-c-blinks-on-lenovo-x1-carbon/1200375#1200375)

Edit: the command to use is `fwupdmgr get-devices`, while `sudo fwupdmgr downgrade` will let you interactively select an older version.  Changing to the below seemed to solve the problem for me:

```
20QD00L1MX System Firmware
  DeviceId:             f09b748a98b31bb5c7c64d83f24ddbc80dff7c5f
  Guid:                 4bbc40fa-f81e-4206-bc70-a1f7b744d964
  Plugin:               uefi
  Flags:                internal|updatable|require-ac|supported|registered|needs-reboot
  Version:              0.1.20
  VersionLowest:        0.0.1
  VersionFormat:        triplet
  Icon:                 computer
  Created:              2020-01-03
  UpdateState:          success
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem has since solved itself with a firmware update, indeed.